# Apps Script editing help - Mail Merge

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, mailmerge

I found some Apps Script which almost does what I want it to with some workarounds. See here https://developers.google.com/apps-script/samples/automations/mail-merge

I made a copy and have done some processing to get data, e.g. [mail merge input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOqFo.png)

The script works but I would like some help with the formatting.

In the email output, rather than being stacked under the Course Name like so:
Person 1
Person 2

The names are adjacent under the Course Name:
Person 1 Person 2

Can anyone support me editing the Apps Script to stack or is this not possible with it being treated like an object?

Unfortunately, I have zero knowledge of objects.

Comment: [Introducing Javascript Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects)

Comment: [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)

Comment: If possible, please include your current script so we can take a look

Comment: Hey thanks for the response, I solved this using HTML in the cells and used <br> to separate them. It worked perfectly.